# iAd across view controllers (Singleton): Somehow not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, singleton, iad

I've been struggling with this now for a long time. Where is my mistake? At the moment the hide and show seems to work, but everytime I come "back" to my viewcontroller I see that my view is shifted up, but there is no ad in there. But the first time I see the view controller, there is an ad. What am I doing wrong? 
I just want to show the same ad across view controllers and this is like the parent UIViewController class, a lot of other view controllers inherit from:

```
#pragma mark View lifecycle
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kInAppPurchaseNoAds]){
        self.bannerContainer = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).bannerView;
        self.bannerContainer.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bannerContainer.frame, 0, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.view addSubview:self.bannerContainer];
    }
}

//Handle the in app purchases
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //iAd
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kInAppPurchaseNoAds] && !self.bannerContainer){
        self.bannerContainer.delegate = self;
    }

    if(self.bannerContainer.bannerLoaded){
        [self showBanner];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkIAdPurchase) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self hideBanner];
    self.bannerContainer.delegate = nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}

#pragma mark Check iAd purchase
-(void)checkIAdPurchase
{
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kInAppPurchaseNoAds] && self.bannerContainer){
        [self hideBanner];
        [self.bannerContainer removeFromSuperview];
        self.bannerContainer.delegate = nil;
        self.bannerContainer = nil;
    }
}

#pragma mark IAd delegate
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [self showBanner];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self hideBanner];
}


#pragma mark Show and hide the banner
- (void)showBanner
{
    if(!self.isBannerVisible){
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             //Restore the constraint
                             self.mainViewBottomConstraint.constant = 50;
                             //Move the banner on
                             self.bannerContainer.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bannerContainer.frame, 0, -50);
                             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             self.isBannerVisible = YES;
                         }];
    }
}

- (void)hideBanner
{
    if(self.isBannerVisible){
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             //Restore the constraint
                             self.mainViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
                             //Move the banner off
                             self.bannerContainer.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bannerContainer.frame, 0, self.bannerContainer.frame.size.height);
                             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             self.isBannerVisible = NO;
                         }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are creating instance of iAd in AppDelegate and that's only one in the whole app.Now when you first time come to Vc then due to code in viewdidload it add to your Vc..

Now when you move to other view controller that viewcontroller also add iAd at viewdidload..You have only one object of iAd so it will add to at a time in One VC..So when you move to other Vc iAd will remove from that Vc and add to new VC..

Solution : You should call iAD subview code in ViewWillAppear...